# Sandbox configuration on paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to test my websites payapl connection using paypal sandbox.

These are the steps  that followed already.

1. Created a Real Paypal account and logged into developer.paypal.com
2. Already created two email accounts which are Business and Personal.
3. Used the Business email as the Merchant on my paypal page.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="gal-facilitator@yahoo.com" />
   ```
4. When i redirected to the paypal page at the check out page, tried to login to the paypal and do the payment using Personal account which is on Developer.paypal.com

But when i do that,

```
Please make sure you have entered your email address correctly.
Please re-enter your PayPal password.
```

I am pretty sure that User Name and password are correct.

Any reason or am i doing anything wrong/

Please point out if anything wrong. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I have been redirecting to the live paypal payment gateway. I need to redirect the user to the sandbox paypal url.
This type of a question can be found here.

[Paypal sandbox - test payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993746/paypal-sandbox-test-payment?rq=1)